# How to find nested value in postgres JSONB using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a postgres table with JSONB column name `entity`. The example of json structure is:

```
{
  "some_key": "some value",
  "properties": {
    "name": ["name_value"],
  }
}
```

I need to find records by `name_value`. I can get it by using query:

```
SELECT entity FROM my_table where entity->'properties' @> {"name": ["name_value"]};
```

The problem is: I cannot find the way to create that same query using sqlalchemy ORM.

**Update**:
My model is made dynamic, because multiple tables are using same structure just the different table name. Here is the code:

```py
...
Base = declarative_base(engine)

class ForeignBase(AbstractConcreteBase, Base):
    pass

def make_model(name):
    class Entity(ForeignBase):
        __tablename__ = name
        __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": name, "concrete": True}
        __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}

        id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
        entity = Column(JSONB, nullable=True)
        ...
    configure_mappers()
    return Entity
```

And then I use 3 functions to initiate my Models and get one I currently need:

```py
def get_model_list():
    tables_names_list = get_table_name_list()
    model_list = [make_model(PREFIX + table_name) for table_name in tables_names_list]
    return model_list

def get_tables_dict():
    return {table.__tablename__: table for table in ForeignBase.__subclasses__()}

def get_table_object(table_name):
    return get_tables_dict().get(table_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following SQLAlchemy expression. The Operator @> is contains() in SQLAlchemy for JSONB columns

```py
Session().query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.entity["properties"].contains({"name": ["name_value"]})).with_entities(MyTable.entity).all()
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Unfortunately it return an empty list `[]`.  It also return the same result without `with_entities` part.

Comment: Print and check the query it is generating. maybe some filter might be missing

Comment: I have tried to print that statement and got `SELECT my_table.entity 
FROM my_table
WHERE ((my_table.entity -> %(entity_1)s)) @> %(param_1)s` . Seems like it should be ok. Just not sure about those double parentheses.

Comment: the query looks to be ok. The double parentheses are not a problem. Maybe the data is not there in the db?

Comment: The data is in db, I have put that raw select into db shell and it find the records. I have double checked. The same record appears on other queries too. Can it be related to `MyTable` model configuration some how?

Comment: Have you tried the raw sql query in db? Does it fetch the correct data? Also can you edit the question and add the `MyTable` model?